# Shortcut to clear terminal doesn't work in Visual Studio Code on MacOS

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, shortcut

Somehow I can't use `⌘ + K` to clear terminal even though the shortcut has set up as default.

[image: terminal clear shortcut]

Comment: Can you double check keybindings.json directly? Can you try `ctrl+l`, which is default shortcut for bash?

Comment: Did you try disabling all extensions to see if any of them were causing the issue?

Comment: @qxg Thank you so much for the answering  
- Checked `keybindings.json` and there is the command
- `ctrl+l` worked  However it doesn't work if any tasks are running.

@jabacchetta Thank you so much for the answering 
- Bingo It was conflicted by [Sublime Text Keymap and Settings Importer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings). I'll try to overwrite the keybindings.

Comment: you should add an anwser (people want to vote either for the question or the answer + the question looks seems to have no answer)

Comment: Did not work, but this worked ". I just went to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts and found the mapping for Clear: workbench.action.terminal.clear did not have a mapping anymore. I added Ctrl + K back, there were no conflicts, and it works fine again. Maybe an oversight on the release?" src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713604/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 1):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@mayognaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1808380)'s question post.

> The command was overwritten by an extension.
> To overwrite it to reset, added the following lines in `keybindings.json`.
>
> `{ "key": "cmd+k", "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear", "when": "terminalFocus" }`
>
> [image: keybindings.json]
> [image: console]