# VS Code Terminal: Cleared Code Keeps reappearing

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have been using VS Code (I have the newest version installed) for over 4 months now.

Today, I was not able to delete the content in the terminal (powershell extension) anymore - even though I did not actively change anything in settings. Anyways, I went to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713604/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-in-visual-studio-code) and setted up everything (somehow the shortcut was not occupied anymore??).
Now I am able to clear most of the terminal, but 3 or 4 lines still remain.

The terminal looks like this now. Between every single query, I cleared the terminal.:

```
hello world
PS D:\Web_Dev\Projekte\cs50_project> py a.py
hello world
PS D:\Web_Dev\Projekte\cs50_project> py a.py
hello world
PS D:\Web_Dev\Projekte\cs50_project> py a.py
hello world
PS D:\Web_Dev\Projekte\cs50_project> py a.py
hello world
```

But I want this:

```
PS D:\Web_Dev\Projekte\cs50_project> py a.py
hello world
```

Comment: As for this...`somehow the shortcut was not occupied anymore??`, did you not just repopulate the settings? Also, the whole, setting for the `When` part of it, is not really necessary. If you leave it blank, it should work for any terminal you are focused on. I cannot reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for your help anyways! Must be some kind of stupidity of me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried restarting pc and vs-code, changing all shortcuts - nothing worked.

I finally fixed by resetting all of my personalized keybindings. Unfortunately, since I had a lot of them, I do not know which one caused the problem.