# VS Code terminal, clear terminal before each run of code

Tags: c, powershell, visual-studio-code

I am learning C Programming currently on VS Code. I run program a lot of time repeatedly which mess up terminal. Mostly I use `cls` before running program to clear previous output of terminal. My default terminal is PowerShell in VS Code. Is there any way to clean terminal before each run.

What I have tried after google search:
-I have tried adding `cls` to powershell profile but it does not work on every code run.
-Checking  `clear previous output` in `coderunner` settings didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add cls to the beginning of your code, but that's not always best:

[image]

You can also set a keyboard shortcut for [clearing the console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48713754/7411885) (Used to be <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, but was removed)

You don't want to replace the existing behavior when running code, but a pretty simple one-button solution could be setting up a vs code macro to do `Terminal: Clear`, and also `run` your open file in the terminal.

Comment: Thnaks for replying, do i have to use this extension [Macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros)  to create it?

Comment: Can you please review this what I've tried. https://pastebin.com/4fh4xUvp . nothing is happening when i press alt+k. Thanks.

Comment: @Pankaj-Talesara yes - I don't use them myself, but they were recommended farther down in the linked question

Comment: @Pankaj-Talesara I think in your settings.json > macro > `macro-name` use `workbench.action.terminal.clear` and `workbench.action.debug.start`

Comment: It worked. Thanks for helping :). what i did: https://pastebin.com/JKaTCs0d

Comment: @Pankaj-Talesara awesome! go ahead and mark it as the answer if it worked for you.