# How to clear python terminal in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, terminal

as I remember I used the command *cls* to clear the terminal, but it doesn't work any longer!
I think the reason is of the update. btw when I use cls it just make the last line, first. and when I scroll up I can see the stuff. What should I do?

Comment: Do you want a command for clearing terminal?

Comment: reset didn't work, and yes I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts and find the mapping for Clear: workbench.action.terminal.clear then change it to Ctrl + K (unless you want to use some other shortcut)

See this stackoverflow post for more information:
[How can I clear the terminal in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48713754/13700906)

Comment: Thanks it worked, but with shortcut k k. Do you know why doesn't cls work anymore?

Comment: @ArshiyaKhavaninzade an update to VS Code must have removed cls functionality. so this shortcut is the next best thing for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Type
`clear`
in treminal to clear it.
`cls` is a command for Windows Command Prompt

Comment: Bro clear didn't work. I'm on windows