# Why does cls in Visual Studio Code Runner only work when CMD is the Terminal Profile but not PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell, terminal, command-prompt, vscode-code-runner

I'm currently using VS Code and I'm trying to make it so that when I run my code, it clears any content in the terminal and it begins from the top. The issue is that when I do this with PowerShell as my terminal profile, it just gives me the shell instead of the code I'm trying to run.

`Python 3.11.7 (tags/v3.11.7:fa7a6f2, Dec  4 2023, 19:24:49) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. >>>`

To clear the content and have it start from the top in the terminal I'm using `cls` in the settings.json file under `"code-runner.executorMap"` like so.

`"python": "cls && python -u"` when by default it's just `"python": "python -u"`.

I was expecting this to work fine since `cls` does the same thing in either a PowerShell or Command Prompt terminal directly, so why is it that when ran through Code Runner on VS Code, it seems to act like this?

When I tried using Command Prompt as the terminal profile, it runs my code just fine, but I was wondering if I could get the PowerShell terminal working the same way, and why `cls` doesn't work with it. I don't have "Clear Previous Output" or "Clear Before Reusing" selected since they only clear the content, but any new lines are still where they would be if that old content was still there.

Comment: because VS Code doesn't have alias for **cls**  
[here is answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713604/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @Re1ter I also tried `clear` instead of `cls` and it just causes the same problem, what would be the original command if not `clear`? That link is about how to assign a key command to clear it, not to have the terminal cleared when you run code.

Answer (score 0):

`cls (or clear) && python -u $fileName` works for me. Try to see if it works for you too.

To be honest I don't have an explanation for this. I got the `$fileName` variable from the other language's way of writing.

My best guess is that for some reason the command is being cut off so it is running `cls (or clear) && python`.